# Magento2: How to show Product Weight on Filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, category-products

Need to show Product Weight on Category Page Filter, so Customer can also filter via Weight.

A user can also enter the weight in Text Box & Search, so it's vice versa between Slider & Textbox.

[image]

Comment: Create new weight attribute and set type "select" then set "Use in Layered Navigation" - "Yes"

Comment: @St3phan that's the last option i have.