# I want to add qty filter same as price filter in layered Navigation in Magento 2

Tags: custom, layered-navigation, plugin, quantity, magento2.3.5-p2

In this i want to develop functionality in which qty filter is added and in that range is displayed in layered navigation as price filter.

- qty range as below:

1 - 50,
50 - 100,
100 - 150, ...

so can anyone have idea then please share with me.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144440/quantity-as-filter-in-layered-navigation

Comment: Hi Abhishek But i want to disaply quantity in magento 2.3.5-p2 so this link will not helpful